# error_log over 70GB. How to stop this?

Tags: errors

I just migrated a website from a host to another. And in one day, my error_log got up to 70GB. How to stop this?

Comment: You should check exactly **what** is causing this. It is unfortunately impossible to pin point something with the info given. I should also note that you should speak to your new host as well as it seems that this issue only happened after moving to a new host

Comment: You would stop your error log by fixing the errors, without any details of what they are, nothing can be done to help within a WordPress context.

Comment: 70GB in one day is nuts, so there's unusual going on which you should fix.  However, you can also configure logrotate to split (and discard) log files when they reach a certain size. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most important thing here would be to figure out what's causing the errors as opposed to just hiding them. 70 GB file might be tough to open, so you can use tail to open up the last several lines of it `tail -f error.log` and see what's going on. Maybe it's a quick fix.

If it's filling up with notices and things you're okay with you might have debugging turned on? Turn it off in wp-config:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );

// don't generate log
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', false );

// don't display errors
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
@ini_set( 'display_errors', false );
```

Comment: It seems I have to define tmp path in wp-config.php, and since my web host doesn't have a tmp directory set up, I will have to contact them. Thanks for the help!